# Finding and Updating record - Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am building an API to store friends names for a game, I have built the API to receive the post request as so :

```
exports.addFriends = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log('hit');
    console.log(req.body.friendNames);
    const addUser = await User.updateOne(
      { uniqueid: req.body.uniqueid },
      { $push: { friendNames: [req.body.friendNames] } }
    );
    res.json({
      addUser
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

ad the post request as

```
      const friends = await axios.post('/api/v1/users/add/friends', {
          uniqueId: this.uniqueid,
          friendNames: [
            {
              userName: 'test',
              region: 'euw'
            }
          ]
        });
```

My API is being hit as a see the logs, but no record is made. My User Schema is as so

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  uniqueid: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  summonerName: {
    type: String
  },
  friendNames: [
    {
      userName: String,
      region: String
    }
  ]
});
```

I get no error and the request seems to go through, but no records are added. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) is used to add one element to the array. But using the [$each](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) array update operator, we can push an array of items.

Also, I used `findOneAndUpdate` with `new:true` option to retrieve the updated document, because updateOne doesn't return the updated document.

```js
exports.addFriends = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.body.friendNames);

    const addUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { uniqueid: req.body.uniqueid },
      { $push: { friendNames: { $each: req.body.friendNames } } },
      { new: true }
    );

    res.json({ addUser });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
  }
}
```

Let's say we have this existing document:

```
{
    "_id": "5e31c749f26d5f242c69f3aa",
    "uniqueid": "uniqueid1",
    "summonerName": "John",
    "friendNames": [
        {
            "_id": "5e31c749f26d5f242c69f3ab",
            "userName": "Max",
            "region": "Germany"
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

Let's send a request to the controller with this request body:

```
{
    "uniqueid": "uniqueid1",
    "friendNames": [
        {
            "userName": "Andrew",
            "region": "England"
        },
        {
            "userName": "Smith",
            "region": "USA"
        }
    ]
}
```

The response will be like this:

```
{
    "addUser": {
        "_id": "5e31c749f26d5f242c69f3aa",
        "uniqueid": "uniqueid1",
        "summonerName": "John",
        "friendNames": [
            {
                "_id": "5e31c749f26d5f242c69f3ab",
                "userName": "Max",
                "region": "Germany"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5e31c763f26d5f242c69f3ad",
                "userName": "Andrew",
                "region": "England"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5e31c763f26d5f242c69f3ac",
                "userName": "Smith",
                "region": "USA"
            }
        ],
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, it still doesnt work. But in postman if i do a post request with this as a body, it does? ```{
          "uniqueid": "cadf385a-fc93-49f7-8de8-e9d11ada4b7a",
          "friendNames": [{ 
           "userName": "Autserenejr",
           "region": "euw" 
          }]
          
}```

Comment: @CameronHowson hi, actually I tested this code, can you show me the document you want to update in json format? Does your User document which you want to update has an uniqueid value cadf385a-fc93-49f7-8de8-e9d11ada4b7a?

Comment: Yeah no worries, {"_id":{"$oid":"5e31d23a0ba9cb42581c32a6"},"uniqueid":"cadf385a-fc93-49f7-8de8-e9d11ada4b7a","friendNames":[],"__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}}

Comment: @CameronHowson what displays in node console when you console.log req.body

Comment: ty for the help, ```Connected to Database...
{ uniqueId: 'cadf385a-fc93-49f7-8de8-e9d11ada4b7a',
  friendNames: [ { userName: 'autserene', region: 'euw' } ] }
```

Comment: @CameronHowson it must be uniqueid not uniqueId. Send request  body like this `{ uniqueid: 'cadf385a-fc93-49f7-8de8-e9d11ada4b7a', friendNames: [ { userName: 'autserene', region: 'euw' } ] }`

Comment: Well you can imagine how i feel right now..thanks so much

Comment: @CameronHowson you are welcome, don't feel bad, it happens to everyone. Can you please accept this as answer and upvote?